# Does following Sacred Hospitality cause stains on any Paths of Enlightenment?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

A lot of the Tzimisce place a *lot* of stock on "Sacred Hospitality" and behaviour according to that. Breaking it being something that can be potentially quite serious, depending on where you are and who knows.

*But,* a lot of the Paths of Enlightenment common to the Sabbat, would seem to advocate against such behaviour - some even being against preventing a death or helping someone weaker, which accepting someone seeking Sacred Hospitality may well entail.

Even the Tzimsice-specific "Path of Metamorphosis" cites against doing things that could be said to be "compassionate".

So, does following the traditions of "Sacred Hospitality" thus indeed break the rules of some paths and cause stains/penalties?

Or does perhaps factors like it being largely out of tradition rather than anything else, prevent acting accordingly to it from counting as proper infractions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it may break some paths' tenets.

Paths are not monolithic laws but guides, the Cainite has a certain degree of freedom but can't go directly opposed to its tenets and sometimes you have tenets that can go against each other in a specific situation and they have to figure things out themselves with that.

The *Path of Honorable Accord* allows and almost enforces the Hospitality tradition (it does for allies) so it's a no-brainer.

Some paths like the *Path of the Feral Heart* or *Path of the Bones* seems to not allow at first this type of interactions but they actually do by their own justifications. The first has *"Failing to support your pack or allies"* that allow a bit of "humane" interaction. The later has 4 tenets that may be contradictory about hospitality; its first 3 are about preventing the death and inconvenience oneself for another but the fourth is *"Making a decision based on emotion rather than logic"*. Hospitality is there for your benefit, you "pay" to be part of the "club", there's a reason for it. Are you preventing a Death? Maybe, maybe not. Tzimisce hospitality is for 3 nights only, if the menace knows about it can just wait outside and let your guest be for the time being to kill them when you kick them out. You did your part, they should do theirs themselves. The *Path of Metamorphosis* are not that far from the *Path of Bones* about hospitality and let you have your own perspective about Hospitality; choose one view and keep it, changing will ruin you because it will be seen as compassion.

Paths like the *Path of Cathari* or the *Path of Night* totally abhors the idea of the Hospitality tradition; don't even try to help another, every damned for themselves.

Please notice that paths that do not allow hospitality have considerable restrictions on how a Cainite can interact with others; their adherents already distance themselves from most normal interactions.